# Creating catalog for each customer in SQL server database

Tags: sql-server, database, full-text-search, catalog

I have 2 tables. A customer table, containing customerID, name, DOB etc and another table which contains some text fields along with the customerID. My customers require to be able to  search through the mentioned text fields in this second table.

This is a simple problem made complicated by the fact that this second table can be very large (several billion records). I am looking at using full text search and have created a full text catalog and full text index for my database and table respectively. Currently this approach is too slow! I was wondering if it is somehow possible to create a full-text catalog for each individual customer?

If you have any other thoughts, I'd be happy to here them

Thanks

Comment: What are your indexes on the catalog table, and are they indexed with the customer_id first? If possible, reorganize your catalog table so that the clustered index is by customer_id then by the primary key, so that the data is stored sequentially by customer_id and each query will hit fewer pages. Finally, it sounds like your problem may be a candidate for solutions like partitioned tables (SQL Server on premise) or sharding (SQL Database on Azure).

Comment: Reading a little more about your problem, it sounds like you may be best off using a table per customer (dynamic SQL to generate queries) or ensuring a seek is used by joining the two tables together and using "WITH (FORCESEEK)" as a join hint (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx)